# How do I center a link with other text next to it?

Tags: html, css

I have pagination at the bottom of a page and I'd like to keep the "Page 1 of 2" centered and just have the "Older" and "Newer" buttons wrap to it, even if there is only one of the two buttons present.

Here's what I currently have:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 540px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.links {} .page {}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="links">Older</a>
  <span class="page">Page 1 of 2</span>
</div>
```

How do I keep "Page 1 of 2" centered in the `div` and just put the "Older" or "Newer" link adjacent to the left or right side of the `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.items {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.item {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.always-left, .always-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.always-left {
    left: 0;
}

.always-right {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper items">
  <a class="item always-left" href="#">Older</a>
  <div class="item">Page 1 of 2</div>
  <a class="item always-right" href="#">Older</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's only one button, i.e. just "older" or "newer".

Comment: This is great, it's actually the one I went with because the other one didn't center according to the `div` width, rather the space between the two words. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 540px;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.links {
  float: left;
}
.newer {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="links older">Older</a>
  <span class="page">Page 1 of 2</span>
  <a href="#" class="links newer">Newer</a>
</div>
```

In order to have the links stick to the left (and right), you need to remove the links from the normal flow, using float.

[View it here](http://codepen.io/pixeline/pen/garrrG?editors=110).

CSS

```
.links{
  float:left;
}
.newer{
  float:right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="links older">Older</a>
  <span class="page">Page 1 of 2</span>
    <a href="#" class="links newer">Newer</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple like that. This will also allow me to move the "older" and "newer" links closer together by shrinking the size of the `div` if need be. This is also the cleanest way to do it, in my opinion.

Comment: One small issue, this is just centering the text in the area between the "r" in older and the "n" in newer. Change the "Older" to "Olddddddder" and you'll see what I'm saying. This isn't noticeable with smaller font sizes when both are present, but I'd like to keep this centered regardless of what's on the left or right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 540px;
    position: relative;
}
.links {
    position: absolute;
    /* half width of the container - width of "Page 1 of 2" - 10px margin */
    left: calc(50% - 73px - 10px);
}
.page {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="links">Older</a>
    <span class="page">Page 1 of 2</span>
</div>
```